# Save Imagedata in the imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

In the app i made an image view that holds the Image chosen from the library of the phone or taken by the camera. But when I go back to the previous scene the image chosen is gone. I want it to be saved in the image view and have a clear button to remove it. The camera function works but the image doesn't stay in the image view.

The camera function: 
.h file

```
@interface FMEImageView : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
UIImagePickerController *picker;

UIImage *image;

}

- (IBAction)Takephoto:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Chosenphoto:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)Takephoto:(id)sender{
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

- (IBAction)Chosenphoto:(id)sender{
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


 }

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[ImageView setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you will have to save images to the documents directory of your application.

Get image data.

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Write it to documents directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];//Choose name for the image. 

[imgData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Get the data and display it on the imageView.

Again, get filePath.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];//Name you have given    

NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

imageView.image = image;
```

It is better to make a function to get the path of documents directory.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Will this work on even though that the image view is empty until i pick an image from the cameraroll library or capturing a photo ?

Comment: Yes! That is the point, right? Unless and until you don't have images, it won't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using new instance every time. use same instance once initialized.